# How to access authentication storage session across modules?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am using a Zend Framework 2 authentication storage session basically the `customer_id` between the user module and product store. I need to show a product based on the `customer_id`.

This is the code

```
$userData_arr = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('user-auth-factory')->getStorage()->read();
 $customerID = $userData_arr->customer_id;
```

In the above I get the **customer_id** in the user module controller and it works. But when I want to access the same variable in product module controller it's empty. This happens only in the live server. In my localhost both the modules are able to get the `customer_id`.

Below is my server info details

```
> Registered serializer handlers    php php_binary
> Directive Local Value Master Value
> session.auto_start    Off Off
> session.cache_expire  180 180
> session.cache_limiter nocache nocache
> session.cookie_domain no value    no value
> session.cookie_httponly   Off Off
> session.cookie_lifetime   0   0
> session.cookie_path   /   /
> session.cookie_secure Off Off
> session.entropy_file  no value    no value
> session.entropy_length    0   0
> session.gc_divisor    100 100
> session.gc_maxlifetime    1440    1440
> session.gc_probability    1   1
> session.hash_bits_per_character   4   4
> session.hash_function 0   0
> session.name  PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
> session.referer_check no value    no value
> session.save_handler  files   files
> session.save_path /tmp    /tmp
> session.serialize_handler php php
> session.upload_progress.cleanup   On  On
> session.upload_progress.enabled   On  On
> session.upload_progress.freq  1%  1%
> session.upload_progress.min_freq  1   1
> session.upload_progress.name
> PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
> session.upload_progress.prefix    upload_progress_    upload_progress_
> session.use_cookies   On  On
> session.use_trans_sid 0   0
```

Below is my localhost config

```
>     Session Support   enabled
>     Registered save handlers  files user
>     Registered serializer handlers    php_serialize php php_binary wddx
>     Directive Local Value Master Value
>     session.auto_start    Off Off
>     session.cache_expire  180 180
>     session.cache_limiter nocache nocache
>     session.cookie_domain no value    no value
>     session.cookie_httponly   Off Off
>     session.cookie_lifetime   0   0
>     session.cookie_path   /   /
>     session.cookie_secure Off Off
>     session.entropy_file  no value    no value
>     session.entropy_length    0   0
>     session.gc_divisor    1000    1000
>     session.gc_maxlifetime    1800    1800
>     session.gc_probability    1   1
>     session.hash_bits_per_character   5   5
>     session.hash_function 0   0
>     session.name  PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
>     session.referer_check no value    no value
>     session.save_handler  files   files
>     session.save_path c:/wamp/tmp c:/wamp/tmp
>     session.serialize_handler php php
>     session.upload_progress.cleanup   On  On
>     session.upload_progress.enabled   On  On
>     session.upload_progress.freq  1%  1%
>     session.upload_progress.min_freq  1   1
>     session.upload_progress.name  
>     PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
>     session.upload_progress.prefix    upload_progress_    upload_progress_
>     session.use_cookies   On  On
>     session.use_only_cookies  On  On
>     session.use_strict_mode   Off Off
>     session.use_trans_sid 0   0
```

Comment: look the difference between both of your environnement. They're iso ?

Comment: thank you. I am very new to zf2 my local server is in windows and the live server is in linux. What exact configuration i need to look to fix the problem

Comment: Ok, If you have a difference between production and local you have to identify where the code is different, or server configuration differs. We can't with so few details, give your a good enought answer we will just guessing... provide more detail or search where the difference between your local and prod are.

Comment: I have updated the post. please see my session config in both server and local. Both looks almost same. But the session variable becomes empty in my server when used across the module

Comment: It's pretty clear to me, you're not iso at all.

Comment: Do you need any more info. It is very difficult to fix this please help